# How can I learn about the network?

Tags: network-health, stats, diagnostics

I'd like to learn about the Tor network in terms of numbers, statistics.

Can I find out how many relays the network has and possibly where they are located?

Can I learn about roles the relays play in the network? For example, how many exits/guards/middle (or combination) are there?

Can I learn about individual relays?

Can I learn about how likely it is to use a given exit/guard?

Whenever you can keep track of users, can I find out how many people use Tor/used Tor? If possible even with where they are coming from and if they used vanilla Tor or a Pluggable Transport.

Can I learn about the performance of the network?

Can I learn if the network is in good shape regarding the network-documents that get published like the consensus?

Can this be done somehow, either with tools developed by someone or websites/service or manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I find out how many relays the network has and possibly where they are located?

The amount of [relays and bridges over time](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html#networksize) is measured. It's also possible to see the [country-specific amount](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html#relaycountries).

> Can I learn about roles the relays play in the network? For example, how many exits/guards/middle (or combination) are there?

The [amount of assigned flags](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html#relayflags) (e.g., "Running", "Guard", "Fast") is also measured.

> Can I learn about individual relays?

There are currently two services: [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) and [Globe](http://globe.rndm.de/). Both are JavaScript-based front ends for the raw data coming from [Onionoo](https://onionoo.torproject.org/).

> Can I learn about how likely it is to use a given exit/guard?

Both Atlas and Globe display diagrams which show the guard and exit probability of a given relay over time.

> Whenever you can keep track of users, can I find out how many people use Tor/used Tor? If possible even with where they are coming from and if they used vanilla Tor or a Pluggable Transport.

There are a number of approximations on the [metrics portal](https://metrics.torproject.org/users.html). It is possible to see the estimated [total users over time](https://metrics.torproject.org/users.html#direct-users), from which countries they are coming from and, since recently, [bridge users by pluggable transport](https://metrics.torproject.org/users.html#userstats-bridge-transport).

> Can I learn about the performance of the network?

The metrics portal has information about, e.g., how long it [takes to download a file over Tor](https://metrics.torproject.org/performance.html).

> Can I learn if the network is in good shape regarding the network-documents that get published like the consensus?

It's possible to see how much [directory traffic is pushed by the authorities](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html#dirbytes).

Answer (score 5):

The Tor project has a website dedicated to network statistics on [metrics.torproject.org](https://metrics.torproject.org/).

Comment: Let us keep this answer, too. I ask anyone who up-voted this answer to up-vote the more verbose answer, which also mentions Atlas and Globe (Onionoo front-ends). Without removing the up-vote for this one obviously. Also down-voting should be avoided on this one.